# Go regular expression with positive lookbehind

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to write a function in Go which will replace `foobar` with `foobaz`, but only if `bar` is preceded by `foo`. It seems to me that the [`regexp.ReplaceAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAll) function together with a positive lookbehind (cf. https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) would work for this, so I tried the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?<=foo)bar`)

    new := re.ReplaceAll([]byte("foobar"), []byte("baz"))

    fmt.Println(string(new))
}
```

The goal was to make this program print `foobaz`, but instead I get a panic because the regular expression doesn't compile:

```
panic: regexp: Compile(`(?<=foo)bar`): error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?<`
```

How can I make this work?

### Note

One thing I've tried is to replace the regular expression with a non-capturing group:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:foo)bar`)
```

However, I find that the program then prints `baz` instead of `foobaz` as desired.

Comment: What's the use of regex here? The requirement "replace `foobar` with `foobaz`, but only if `bar` is preceded by `foo`" is rather strange, seeing as how `foobar` is just a static string and that condition will always be met.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

look like your issue is only static string replacement. can simply done with [strings.Replace](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace)

but if you do want lookbehind:

Go's `regexp` package don't support lookbehind, you can check the supported feature here: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

if you do need lookbehind, you should try third-party module, for example: https://github.com/dlclark/regexp2